# Updating an entity with typeorm

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I'm new to typeorm and I'm a little confused as to how to update an entity in my case.

I have this method at the moment:

```
    public async createCategoryByUserId(userId: number, createCategoryDto: CreateCategoryDto): Promise<Category> {
        const category = await this.categoryRepository.createQueryBuilder('category')
                                                      .where('category.user.id = :userId', {userId})
                                                      .andWhere('category.id = :id', {id: createCategoryDto.id})
                                                      .getOne();

        const subcategory = new CategoryEntity();
        subcategory.setName(createCategoryDto.name)
                   .setIsBaseTemplate(false)
                   .setSection(category.section);

        await this.categoryRepository.save(subcategory);

        const newCategory = new CategoryEntity();

        Object.assign(newCategory, category);

        const subcategories = (await this.categoryRepository.createQueryBuilder('category')
                                   .where('category.user.id = :userId', {userId})
                                   .andWhere('category.id = :id', {id: createCategoryDto.id})
                                   .leftJoinAndSelect('category.subcategories', 's')
                                   .getOne()).subcategories;

        newCategory.subcategories = [...subcategories, subcategory];

        await this.categoryRepository.save(newCategory);
        return;
    }
```

Here each category can have subcategories (they belong to the same table and are represented by the same entity). The client passes the object `createCategoryDto` which contains two parameters: `id` of the new category/subcategory to which a new subcategory (so far the client can only create subcategories) should be appended and the second parameter is `name`.

It sort of works but what I don't like about it is that I have to pull all the subcategories from the DB (there should not be too many of them but still it's just wrong) and the second thing that looks wrong to me is that even though the category has the `userId` field when I create a subcategory this way the `userId` is missing.

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Anyone?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't figure out how to update embedded entity in typeorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62282150/cant-figure-out-how-to-update-embedded-entity-in-typeorn)

Comment: @Yevhenii eerrrm it's another question of mine, as you see it has not been answered.